# Rebasing current patchset in Gerrit onto another branch

Tags: git, gerrit

At the project I work on there are two branches: Main and Feature.
I have worked on Feature branch and pushed to Gerrit and got some reviews(I have 10 patchsets at the moment on the Feature branch).
Now I want to rebase the Feature branch onto the Main branch but also keep the history of reviews and patchsets(so not like a cherry pick which picks just the last commit and does not keep history). 
Is it possible to do this? I know I can do a merge but will this keep the history of the review that was done on the Feauture branch when I will push the new commit(after merge) to Main?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is the Feature branch a local branch or a branch on Gerrit? Did you push to refs/for/master or refs/for/Feature

Comment: The Feature branch is a local branch which tracks the remote branch with the same name. I have pushed to refs/for/Feature(I have few patchsets but it was not merged yet) and now I want to rebase all the commits(patchsets) that I have done on refs/for/Feature into Main.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to bring the feature to the main branch is to make a merge. Doing a merge is very simple and yes... you'll keep all the history of the review on the Feature branch.

Do the following:

1. Finish the review work on Feature branch, approve and submit the
   change
2. Checkout the Main branch in your local repository
3. Fetch (git fetch) and merge the Feature branch (git merge
   origin/Feature)
4. If needed, solve the conflicts (git mergetool)
5. Push to the Main branch to review (git push origin
   HEAD:refs/for/Main)
6. Review, approve and submit the change

Comment: I have pushed to review to the Feature branch. I have like 10 patchsets but it was not yet merged. I want to move all the patchsets with the history of remarks from reviews to Main and continue the review there.

Comment: You can move your change if you really want (look at the other answer in this question) but the "Move change" feature is to be used in the case you pushed to the wrong branch (is it your case?). If you're really working in a feature branch, the correct is to review and submit first and then merge the result to the main branch.

Comment: Not sure about that 'move change' gerrit option. I assume that will not work if I have conflicts(and I have a lot). I think the solution is to rebase Feature on top of Main(solve the conflicts) and then push. Is that correct?
As in: 
git checkout Feature
git rebase Main
git checkout Main
git merge Feature

Would that work for what I want to do?

Comment: I added more details to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your change from the Feature branch to the master branch. This will not change the parent but after having moved it your can rebase your change on the tip of the master.

This is almost like a cherry-pick but you keep the history
[image]