# Gerrit move patchset to merged branch

Tags: gerrit

There are two (remote)branches in our project: dev and master. dev diverged from master some time ago and was used for development. I have some patchsets which are pending on dev (pushed to refs/for/dev and have review comments etc), but now dev has been merged into master and the patchset needs to be submitted to master instead of dev.

I would like to move the patchset from dev to master now since dev is no longer being used.
When I try cherry-picking the change onto master I get an error:

> Cherry Pick Conflict! Cherry Pick failed! (merge conflicts) Please
> select "Continue" to continue with conflicts or select "cancel" to
> close the dialog.

and if I continue anyway I get this error:

> An error occurred Could not perform action: Cannot create new patch
> set of change 562407 because it is abandoned

If I try moving the change to master (suggested here: [Rebasing current patchset in Gerrit onto another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418748/rebasing-current-patchset-in-gerrit-onto-another-branch)) I get this error:

> An error occurred Could not perform action: Destination master has a
> different change with same change key
> Ie63692606xxx5841xxxxca2687ebxxxaa8f84d2

How can I get the change with all the comments etc. onto the master branch now? If not, how do I create a new change on the master branch for the same patch set?

If I checkout the patch and try git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master, I still get an error.

Comment: This behavior is highly specific to Gerrit, which takes the `refs/for` stuff and then interprets it. You won't see this behavior in anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I had another patchset with the same changeId on the master which I had abandoned earlier, which is why the move patchset didn't work. After I deleted the abandoned patchset, I was able to move the change to the master branch (with conflicts that I now need to resolve.).